# Растянуть видео на весь экран

Tags: java, videoview, android

Как принудительно растянуть videoview на весь экран?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

если тебе нужно растянуть **videoView** на весь экран, то достаточно задать для него **layoutheight** и **layoutwidth** как **fillparent**

если нужно растянуть само видео в **videoView**, то надо сабкласснуть **VideoView** и переопрелелить метод **onMeasure**. пример кода есть [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434027/android-videoview-orientation-change-with-buffered-video/4452597#4452597)